# Apache Karaf ColorPalette error in windows

Tags: apache-karaf

Apache Karaf 4.3.0 in windows 10.
I try to install a feature and got the below error, could anyone help me to find what could cause this error. It comes out the shell as well. After that if I again start, I get the same error and stops.

```
...\apache-karaf-4.3.0\bin>karaf
karaf.bat: Ignoring predefined value for KARAF_HOME
karaf.bat: KARAF_LOG doesn't exist: "...\sw\apache-karaf-4.3.0\bin\..\data\log"
karaf.bat: Creating "...\sw\apache-karaf-4.3.0\bin\..\data\log"
karaf.bat: JAVA_HOME not set; results may vary


  Apache Karaf (4.3.0)

Hit '<tab>' for a list of available commands
and '[cmd] --help' for help on a specific command.
Hit '<ctrl-d>' or type 'system:shutdown' or 'logout' to shutdown Karaf.

karaf@root()> feature:repo-add mvn:org.apache.karaf.examples/karaf-blueprint-example-features/LATEST/xml
Adding feature url mvn:org.apache.karaf.examples/karaf-blueprint-example-features/LATEST/xml
karaf@root()> feature:install karaf-blueprint-example-provider
Error executing command: Method org/apache/karaf/shell/impl/console/JLineTerminal.getPalette()Lorg/jline/utils/ColorPalette; is abstract
```

Comment: I've got the exact same error after installing activemq.

Comment: I'm on Mac OS Catalina.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KARAF-6996 you can try adding the Karaf 4.3.1-SNAPSHOT repositories to the blacklisted repositories.

Just add `etc/org.apache.karaf.features.xml` containing:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<featuresProcessing xmlns="http://karaf.apache.org/xmlns/features-processing/v1.0.0">

    <!--
        Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one or more
        contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file distributed with
        this work for additional information regarding copyright ownership.
        The ASF licenses this file to You under the Apache License, Version 2.0
        (the "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance with
        the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at


            http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0


        Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
        distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
        WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
        See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
        limitations under the License.
    -->

    <blacklistedRepositories>
        <repository>mvn:org.apache.karaf.features/framework/4.3.1-SNAPSHOT/xml/features</repository>
        <repository>mvn:org.apache.karaf.features/standard/4.3.1-SNAPSHOT/xml/features</repository>
        <repository>mvn:org.apache.karaf.features/enterprise/4.3.1-SNAPSHOT/xml/features</repository>
        <repository>mvn:org.apache.karaf.features/enterprise-legacy/4.3.1-SNAPSHOT/xml/features</repository>
        <repository>mvn:org.apache.karaf.features/spring/4.3.1-SNAPSHOT/xml/features</repository>
        <repository>mvn:org.apache.karaf.features/spring-legacy/4.3.1-SNAPSHOT/xml/features</repository>
        <repository>mvn:org.apache.karaf.features/framework/4.3.0-SNAPSHOT/xml/features</repository>
        <repository>mvn:org.apache.karaf.features/standard/4.3.0-SNAPSHOT/xml/features</repository>
        <repository>mvn:org.apache.karaf.features/enterprise/4.3.0-SNAPSHOT/xml/features</repository>
        <repository>mvn:org.apache.karaf.features/enterprise-legacy/4.3.0-SNAPSHOT/xml/features</repository>
        <repository>mvn:org.apache.karaf.features/spring/4.3.0-SNAPSHOT/xml/features</repository>
        <repository>mvn:org.apache.karaf.features/spring-legacy/4.3.0-SNAPSHOT/xml/features</repository>
        <repository>mvn:org.apache.karaf.features/framework/4.3.0.RC1/xml/features</repository>
        <repository>mvn:org.apache.karaf.features/standard/4.3.0.RC1/xml/features</repository>
        <repository>mvn:org.apache.karaf.features/enterprise/4.3.0.RC1/xml/features</repository>
        <repository>mvn:org.apache.karaf.features/enterprise-legacy/4.3.0.RC1/xml/features</repository>
        <repository>mvn:org.apache.karaf.features/spring/4.3.0.RC1/xml/features</repository>
        <repository>mvn:org.apache.karaf.features/spring-legacy/4.3.0.RC1/xml/features</repository>
    </blacklistedRepositories>

</featuresProcessing>
```

This worked for me.